# How can I change theme for background color?

Tags: theme

I can't find background color option in the Preferences>Themes>3D View menu. 
Where is it?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Preferences -> Themes -> 3D View ->Theme Space -> Gradient colors -> Gradient high/off

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewport background instead:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer !